# atoi in C returning -1

Tags: c, atoi

I'm trying to read some input in a C program but for some reason `atoi` is returning `-1`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Follow my input and my code:

**Input**:

```
20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722
53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690
```

**Algorithm**:

```
loop here ( i++, j-- ) {

      printf( "%c %d\n", A[ i ][ j ], atoi( &A[ i ][ j ] ) );

}
```

**Output**:

```
...
2 -1
5 -1
```

Look that `2` and `5` is the first numbers of the input. So printing as `%c` is working as expected but the `atoi`function is not working properly.

Comment: What's your & about suddenly?

Comment: Please fix your formatting and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show a complete example. We don't know what A is.

Comment: "...`atoi` function is not working properly". What did you expect `atoi` function would do in this case? What do you see as "working properly"?

Comment: Chapter 1 of your beginner-level programming book likely addresses integer sizes and ranges. Read that chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it appears that you are actually trying to convert a *single digit character* from `'0'..'9'` range to its corresponding integer representation from `0..9` range. `atoi` is not supposed to do that. `atoi` expects a *string* as its input and single character is not a string. There are no functions in standard library for converting a single character, albeit you can easily do it manually by subtracting `'0'` from the character value.

Secondly, `atoi` produces undefined behavior on overflow, which is what happens in your code, considering the size of the input. Don't use `atoi`. The function is essentially useless. If you want to convert a string, use functions from `strto...` group.

Comment: Thanks man! I thought that using `atoi` it could convert all strings (even char) into integer values.

Answer (score 1):

You forget that strings in C are a sequence of characters followed by a terminator. The expression `A[ i ][ j ]` is a single character, and passing the address to that character does not create a string, leading [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) to overflow and possible even go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

However, since the C standard requires that all digits should be encoded contiguously you can easily get the number from a single character by doing e.g.  `A[ i ][ j ] - '0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your input values bigger than INT type